# Where do objects get stored when a cloud function downloads something?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Suppose I deploy a Google Cloud Function with Python 3 to download an object from Google Cloud Storage. The code to download an object is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#rest-download-object). My question is: if I call this function, where does the file get downloaded to? Can I use it then "locally" in the same script after downloading it?

My specific goal is to download a `.mp3` file and then using [mutagen](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen) to read its metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code specifies the download location when you call the Cloud Storage API.  The file location is never determined automatically.

The only writable path in Cloud Functions is /tmp, which is a memory-based filesystem.  Be sure to [read the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) about that.